# How to get Android Studio 1.1.0 to not use default folders and pay attention to env. variable?

Tags: android, android-studio

Specifically, on Windows 7 Pro SP1, it uses `C:/Users/Alan/{.android,.AndroidStudio,.gradle}`.  I want it to use `S:/Android/{SDK_Home,SDK_Root}/{.android,.AndroidStudio,.gradle}`.

I have tried setting environment variables:  `ANDROID_SDK_HOME = S:\Android\SDK_Home and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = S:\Android\SDK_Root`.  But it makes no difference.  This persists after uninstalling Studio 1.0 and all files and folders and creating blank ones appropriately and installing and re-installing Studio 1.1.0.

The install does use the Home and Root folders to store about 3 GB of files (as I made a setting in the Install process), but it still puts an additional about 300 MB in the User directory and it doesn't put .gradle on the S drive as I would like.  The User directories continue to grow as Android is used.  It seems to not use C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local anymore (thank goodness for small favors).  I can't have any space taken on the C drive as it is already too full, especially if AS is growing the space it uses.

Robert suggests running a bat file to start the Studio, but it is not clear how to start the studio from a shell.  I did see instructions on the Android developer site for starting an app from a shell, but not the studio.  Running tools/android.bat starts the SDK Manager but not Studio.  He says to set the environment variables in some bat file but they are already set in the operating system.

In any case, that doesn't solve the problem of Android Studio ignoring the settings it asks of the user during installation and ending up eating space in the C drive when the user has explicitly asked for this to not happen.

I've tried searching with terms like "move .AndroidStudio folder" and "Android Studio environment variables", but it seems to almost all be talking about the Java variable (which works fine).

Since I'm just starting an Android project I don't mind wiping and re-installing as needed.

Comment: Use the shel. When you run AS a bat file is called. Change that to call SET_ENV. Pick correct env vars by inspecting the script

Comment: Thanks @Robert.  Which bat file?  There is no bat file in bin.  There are a bunch of bat files in tools, one of which is android.bat.  Is that it?  It doesn't set any environment variables.  Since I have set Android environment variables already, setting them there shouldn't make a difference. [p]Android is using the S drive folders and has installed 3 GB there but is still using the User folder and it is growing.  [p]The User folder get 300 MB during installation despite setting folders in install.  [p]Due to limitations in comments I think I will go edit the question.

Comment: ummm. i dont use windows .. on linux, AS runs from $root/bin/studio.sh  - so look for the windows analog... set your ENV-VARS there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a year later, and thus for a different version of studio (2.2), but here's the answer.  Below, the new user and/or config folder will have a full path of `C:\new`.

1) Copy the idea.properties file (which can be found either in the .AndroidStudio folder or in studio's /bin) to `C:\new\idea.properties`. Next, set the STUDIO_PROPERTIES environment variable to that location (`STUDIO_PROPERTIES = C:\new\idea.properties`).

2) Repeat step one for studio.exe.vmoptions or studio64.exe.vmoptions (probably the second one if you're developing in 64-bit), this time setting an environment variable called STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS to that file's location.

3) Open your new copy of idea.properties and set idea.config.path and idea.system.path to `C:/new/config` and `C:/new/system` respectively (there should be a template for both near the top that's commented out -- also note the forward slashes).

4) Set ANDROID_SDK_HOME and GRADLE_USER_HOME to C:\new

5) Set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to the root of your sdk installation, if that's non-standard.

Note that a .AndroidStudio2.2\system folder still gets created in your user folder, but it does not seem to be used.

This answer was compiled by combining [this blog post](http://www.laurivan.com/android-studio-change-the-cache-location/) with [this page from the Android Studio docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration).

Comment: Thanks much for the answer. It seems likely to work.  I have shifted to another machine for development and AS 2.2.3.  If I need to go back to the laptop, I'll give this a try.  Should I "accept" this answer in the meantime?

Comment: Accepting the answer is up to you.  I just had to re-run this process (thanks to having to go back to *my* laptop), so the process described is up to date with 2.2 (no changes were needed, but I ended up filling the answer out a bit by mentioning GRADLE_USER_HOME and such).